# Count the amount of vowels in a sentence and display the most frequent

Tags: python, counter, counting

This is my code so far for counting vowels. I need to to scan through a sentence, count and compare the vowels and then display the top occurring vowels.

```
from collections import Counter
vowelCounter = Counter()
sentence=input("sentence")
for word in sentence:
    vowelCounter[word] += 1
vowel, vowelCount= Counter(vowel for vowel in sentence.lower() if vowel in "aeiou").most_common(1)[0]
```

Does anyone have a better way to do this ?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Why do you have both the for loop and the `vowel, vowelCount=` line? It looks to me like the latter line will solve your problem as it is.

Comment: you can sort it first and then go in O(n) time threw it

Comment: @DavidRobinson is there a way to extract the top 5 most common and set them to different variables like vowelA, countA, vowelB and CountB etc?

Answer (score 2):

IMO, long lines are best avoided for the sake of clarity:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import collections

sentence = input("sentence").lower()
vowels = (c for c in sentence if c in "aeiou")
counter = collections.Counter(vowels)
most_common = counter.most_common(1)[0]
print(most_common)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you are after is the max-occurrent vowel, you don't really need `Counter`.

```
counts = {i:0 for i in 'aeiou'}
for char in input("sentence: ").lower():
  if char in counts:
    counts[char] += 1
print(max(counts, key=counts.__getitem__))
```

Comment: You should use `counts[char] = counts.get(char, 0) + 1`.

Comment: @hcwhsa: Thanks for the bugreport. I was looking ONLY for vowels, which is why I initialized the `dict` the way I did; but I did forget an if-statement