# Counting Vowels in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string

**I have been 'flagged' for posting a duplicate question.** However, my question was not the same, as the other coder was asking how to "count how many occurrences there are of specific characters in a string". My output was not counting the occurrences of specific characters, but counting a total of specific characters (all vowels) in the string. For example the other guy was looking for the output to be:

```
A:1 E:6 I:2
```

I was also looking for a total of the numbers, so my output should be: `9` (granted we are speaking about the same string in both codes)."

I have created a piece of code but for some reason it is counting all letters, not just the vowels. I cannot figure out what part I went wrong at.

```
vowels = 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'

ip_str = raw_input("Enter a string: ")
ans = str(raw_input)

count = (0)

for letters in ans:
    if letters in vowels:
        count += 1

print str(count)
```

Comment: You will need to include your code as text and not as a link to an image.

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot, you should post the actual text

Comment: well you never use `ip_str`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count Vowels in String Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python)

Comment: and more to the point, you cast raw_input (a function) to a string and use that instead of ip_str

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this website. I looked around to see if anyone had already asked this question, and I thought that others had posted screenshots of their code. Next time I will post as text. I didn't use ip_str because I was confused and thought that it would count the raw_input answer with the "Enter a string: " vowels and that I could use ans to keep the input that was collected separate from the string. I don't know if that makes sense, but in my head I thought it did. I am very new to this and trying really hard to learn and understand it.

Comment: And @timgeb I searched the website before I posted my question, and no question or responses gave me any clarification to my problem. I have edited my post with the differentiation between the other coders issue and mine. I understand I used the same title as the other question, but they are in fact different. I am sure if y'all took a minute to look at the other coders question, y'all would be aware of that as well. Like I've said previously, I'm new at this so a little more understanding would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a few things wrong here. First, let me correct it, and then I'll explain:

```
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

ans = raw_input("Enter a string: ")

count = 0
for letters in ans:
    if letters in vowels:
        count += 1

print str(count)
```

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) is a function, not a variable. I think you meant `str(ip_str)`, but there's no need to do that, since `raw_input` will always return a string:

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

So, we can just directly set `ans = raw_input("Enter a string: ")`.

Now, for a couple of matters of style: `vowels` is a tuple, and putting `()`'s around it makes that more clear. It will work fine either way. `count` is just a simple `int`, and doesn't need any `()`'s around the definition.

In short, though, the only thing actually wrong with it was how you were defining `ans`.

Comment: I am so thankful for your input and for you taking the time to help me out! This was very useful and helped me understand where I messed up at. Now the code works perfectly and I am so grateful! I kept staring at it but had "writers block" and couldn't understand where I was going wrong. I am very new at this but am trying to work really hard to learn and understand it. Thanks a million! I would vote up your answer but unfortunately I don't have any reputation yet. This was my first question posted on this site. Thanks again!

Comment: I missed your comment before, but thank you! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You store the input in the `ip_str` variable but you never actually use that variable again. You want to be using that variable when iterating. Note that in your code when you have:

```
>>> str(raw_input)
'<built-in function raw_input>'
```

this actually gets the name of the builtin function and stores that in `ans` and not your input. So every time you run you are getting the number of vowels in `'<built-in function raw_input>'` instead of your input, this will always be 9.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer. Ironically enough I was testing the code with my name "Mackenzie" and that has 9 letters as well so I assumed it was counting all letters. I would rate your answer up but I don't have any reputation yet. This was my first question asked. But thanks a million, that explained a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little bit and this works completely fine for me.

```
vowels = 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'

inp = input("Enter a string: ")

count = 0

for letters in inp:
    if letters in vowels:
        count += 1


print("Count: " + str(count))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_input("string")
```

This is a function that takes a string as parameter, prints that string, gets input from the user and then stores that in the valueable you store the entire function( as in:   variable1 = raw_input("string")  will prompt you with "string" and then waits for your input, then stores that input in variable1)