# Python: Counting Vowels from List

Tags: python

I'm new to python and having some difficulty troubleshooting my script.

My assignment is to create some function that accepts a list of strings and returns the number of vowels within the entire list.

The game plan I'm attempting to follow is:

1. Merge list elements into a single string
2. Create a loop that tests if a string element is a vowel
3. Use a counter variable to keep track of vowels in string
4. Print the value of the counter variable when finished with loop

My code is not elegant, but it also does not work.

```
def vowelCounter(listName):
    new = ''.join(listName)
    n = len(new)
    count = 0
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    i = 0
    for i in range(0,n):
        while i < n:
            if new[i] in vowels:
                count += 1
                i += 1
                return
            print count
            return
        return
    return

print(vowelCounter(["terrapin","station","13points"]))
```

Please forgive any stupid errors I may have. I will certainly appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count Vowels in String Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python)

Comment: You should definitely learn at least the basics of a language before posting questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first, we have some general syntax problems.

1. `return` exits from the function immediately; it doesn't just "end the loop".
2. There's no point in initializing `i` to `0` above the loop. The `for` loop itself will just automatically set `i` to the current value in the list that `range()` returns.
3. The `while i < n` is unnecessary; there's no need to loop through the string again for each character in the list.
4. There is no need to manually increment `i`; `for` will do this for you automatically.
5. You're `print`ing the value inside the function, but you're also trying to print the return value of the function (but it doesn't return anything!).

So, if we fixed those issues, we'd have something like this:

```
def vowelCounter(listName):
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    new = ''.join(listName)
    count = 0

    for i in range(0, len(new)):
        if new[i] in vowels:
            count += 1

    return count
```

But Python also allows the `for` loop to just iterate through each character of a string, so we don't need `range()` and `len()` at all:

```
def vowelCounter(listName):
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    count = 0

    for char in ''.join(listName):
        if char in vowels:
            count += 1

    return count
```

But we can make this even awesomer, with [List Comprehensions](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) and the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function!

```
def vowelCounter(listName):
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    count = sum([1 for char in ''.join(listName) if char in vowels])
    return count
```

What we basically do here, is to make a list of `1`s for each letter that is a vowel (and if it's not a vowel, we don't put anything in our new list). Then we use `sum()` to add up all of the numbers (1's) in the list, which is our total number of vowels.

Or we could even make this a one-liner:

```
def vowelCounter(listName):
    return sum([1 for char in ''.join(listName) if char in 'aeiouAEIOU'])
```

Comment: Talk about elegance... Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: No problem, thanks, glad to help! Python is very flexible and expressive, and there's always a few correct approaches, but the goal is usually to find one that's the right combination of simple, efficient, but also readable. You we're definitely on the right track though!

Comment: @MattD If you think that this answer was good and sufficient, and correct (of course), you should go ahead and accept it, :)

Answer (score 2):

The step-by-step logic you supplied is correct.
However, the code you posted does not follow the logic and is incorrect.

Try the following code instead:

```
def vowelCounter(listName):
    string = ''.join(listName)
    count = 0
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    for ch in string:
        if ch in vowels:
            count += 1
    return count

print(vowelCounter(["terrapin","station","13points"]))
```

Comment: Is print necessary to display the value that the function returns?

Comment: Yes, the function returns the vowel count. So print is necessary to display the value returned from the function.

Comment: However, you may print the vowel count directly from inside the function by replacing the last line `return count` with the following two lines `print count` and `return`

Answer (score 1):

The code is mostly ok... however

- a `for i in ...` automatically increments `i`, so `i += 1` is not needed
- the `for` does the looping... no need to put another `while` loop inside it
- `return` quits the function and you should only use it at the very end to give back the result that has been computed with `return count`

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply! I will make changes and see what I can fix.

Comment: I smell a rat! Even this nice little answer gets downvote. Anyway, I am doing what I can, bringing it to earth-line!

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import re
>>> vowels = re.compile('[AEIOU]', re.IGNORECASE)
>>>
>>> def vowelCounter(listName):
...     return len(vowels.split("".join(listName)))-1
...
>>> vowelCounter(["terrapin","station","13points"])
8
>>> vowelCounter(["terrapin","station","13pOInts"])
8
```

Comment: Beautiful! Very neat and clever. +1 but the OP wants more naive answer possibly `:-)`

Comment: Regex is also not very efficient for such a problem.