# Counting number of vowels in a merged string

Tags: python, list

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the score of two merged lists of names. I need to give one point for each character (including spaces between first and last name) plus one point for each vowel in the name. I can currently calculate score for the the lengths of the names but cannot figure out how to include the number of vowels.

```
a = ["John", "Kate", "Oli"]
b = ["Green", "Fletcher", "Nelson"]

vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

gen = ((x, y) for x in a for y in b)

score = 0

for first, second in gen:
    print first, second
    name = first, second
    score = len(first) + len(second) +1
    for letter in name:
        if letter in vowel:
            score+1
    print score
```

**This is what i currently have and this is the output I get:**

```
John Green
10
John Fletcher
13
John Nelson
11
Kate Green
10
Kate Fletcher
13
Kate Nelson
11
Oli Green
9
Oli Fletcher
12
Oli Nelson
10
```

**This is the output I need:**

```
Full Name: John Green Score: 13 
Full Name: John Fletcher Score: 16 
Full Name: John Nelson Score: 14 
Full Name: Kate Green Score: 14 
Full Name: Kate Fletcher Score: 17 
Full Name: Kate Nelson Score: 15 
Full Name: Oli Green Score: 13 
Full Name: Oli Fletcher Score: 16
Full Name: Oli Nelson Score: 14
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python

Comment: Instead of that generator expression you can use `itertools.product`.

Comment: And this question in itself is about a simple typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not calculating the vowels is because the score variable is not getting incremented. To increment it, you have to set the variable score to previous score + 1.

This should work:

```
for letter in name:
    if letter in vowel:
        score+=1
```

Edit: It's worth writing that score+=1 is the same as score=score+1

I worked out the error - instead of creating name = first, second, initialize name to first+second. You will get the results you want. The reason it was failing is because name=first, second creates a tuple, and iterating through the tuple makes letter = "Kate", "John" etc, and not the actual individual characters.

Comment: When i change it to that it still comes out with the same output as before. Doesn't seem to be adding the vowels.

Comment: Check out my edit - you were initializing name to a tuple. Instead, concatenate the strings to create the name variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["John", "Kate", "Oli"]
b = ["Green", "Fletcher", "Nelson"]
vowel = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}
names = (first + ' ' + last for first in a for last in b)

for name in names:
    score = len(name) + sum(c in vowel for c in name.lower())
    print "Full Name: {name} Score: {score}".format(name=name, score=score)
```

---

```
Full Name: John Green Score: 13
Full Name: John Fletcher Score: 16
Full Name: John Nelson Score: 14
Full Name: Kate Green Score: 14
Full Name: Kate Fletcher Score: 17
Full Name: Kate Nelson Score: 15
Full Name: Oli Green Score: 13
Full Name: Oli Fletcher Score: 16
Full Name: Oli Nelson Score: 14
```