# Write a function that returns a list for the number of vowels per line

Tags: python

Define a function lineStats() that takes one parameter:
1. paragraph, a string of words and white spaces
The function returns a list containing the number of vowels in each line.
for example,

```
t="Apple\npear and kiwi" 
print(lineStats(t))
[2,5]
```

This is what I have. I've gotten the output to be 7 but not to be able to make it 2,5. I tried to make a counter for each line but that didn't work, any suggestions?

```
def lineStats(paragraph):
    vowels = "AEIOUaeiou"
    for line in paragraph:
        for word in line:
            for letter in word:
                if letter in vowels:
                    counter +=1
                else:
                    continue

    return counter

t = "Apple\npear and kiwi"
print(lineStats(t))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count Vowels in String Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create this function

```
def temp(x):      
    return sum(v for k, v in Counter(x).items() if k.lower() in 'aeiuo')
```

Now

```
from collections import Counter 

print [temp(x) for x in lines.split('\n')]
```

Comment: Once your list comprehensions start becoming _that_ long, you should seriously consider using regular for loops. The terseness gained by using a list comprehension is far outweighed by the readability of using a regular for loop.

Comment: @ChristianDean Surrender? Never!!! ;-) Seriously: in that case I would rather create functions (which I just did). :-)

Comment: Alright, now that you've split some of your code up into a function, I guess I'll let it slide this time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Changing as little of your code as necessary, other answers offer improvements.

```
def lineStats(paragraph):
    counter = []
    vowels = "AEIOUaeiou"
    lines = paragraph.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        count = 0
        for word in line:
            for letter in word:
                if letter in vowels:
                    count +=1
                else:
                    continue
        counter.append(count)
    return counter

t = "Apple\npear and kiwi"
print(lineStats(t))        # [2, 5]
```

The problem states it wants the result to be a `list` of counts, so changing `counter` to be a `list` that we can [append](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) to, then use that list to store the vowel count for each line. That may be the only *major* change to your code that you need to get the required output.

However, there is the concern of newlines (`'\n'`) in the "paragraph", so we `str.split()` the paragraph into individual lines before entering the `for`-loop. This will break the count for each line, instead of the total count that you were getting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adaption of your current code

```
def lineStats(paragraph):
    vowels = "AEIOUaeiou"
    counter = []
    current_line_count = 0
    newline = "\n"

    for letter in paragraph:
        if letter in vowels:
            current_line_count += 1
        elif letter == newline:
            counter.append(current_line_count)
            current_line_count = 0
    counter.append(current_line_count)
    return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t="Apple\npear and kiwi" 

def lineStats(p):
    #find vowels in each line and sum the occurences using map
    return map(sum, [[1 for e in f if e in "AEIOUaeiou"] for f in p.split('\n')])

lineStats(t)
Out[601]: [2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // define a function's return a voyels in a phrase and there number
    
    function voyelsInPhrase(mots){
           const wordFromVoyels = mots;
            const frenchVoyelle=['a','e','i','o','u','y','A','E','I','O','U','Y'];
            let numberOfVoyels = [];
            for(let i in frenchVoyelles){
                if(wordFromVoyels.includes(frenchVoyelles.at(i))){
                     numberOfVoyels.push(frenchVoyelles.at(i));
            }
        }
           console.log(` the voyels in this phrase is ${numberOfVoyels}, there are ${numberOfVoyels.length}`);

}

    // e.g Execute function voyelsPhrase
voyelsInPhrase('mangerioayuopg');
```

Comment: Visit my github https://github.com/Jumvi/Basic-Javascripst.git for more basic Javascript exercices and contribute with your another exerccises and comment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).