# Need help in developing this code

Tags: python-3.x

Assume s is a string of lower case characters.

Write a program that counts up the number of vowels contained in the string s. Valid vowels are: 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', and 'u'. For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', your program should print:

Number of vowels: 5

I came up with this code but I might be missing out on something I can't quite figure out yet

```
s = 'fddjhkloeavhkiyaeio'
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
count = 0

for i in s:
    if i in vowels:
        count = count + 1
    print("Number of vowels: " , str(count))
```

this is the error 
Number of vowels:  8

*** ERROR: Expected 6, got 8. ***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count Vowels in String Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python)

Comment: bring the `print` line back 2 indentions

Comment: whats the issue here. Do you get an error. If so please edit your question and add the exact error.

Comment: The `print` statement should be outside of the `for` loop, at the end.

Comment: good point. also "in" is a very general way of doing this.

Comment: how should I do it? abdulrahman attia

Comment: Why would you expect 6? There are 8 vowels in `fddjhkloeavhkiyaeio`

Comment: is this code correct?  castis Why I'm I getting this error

Comment: The code itself produces no errors.

Comment: Your code is correct.

Comment: Also, consider adding your code in a function so that you can return the number of vowels

Answer (score 1):

You have a issue first pointed out by @castis above. Your print statement is in the wrong place. If you put it inside the for loop, it means that it will print every time the for loop iterates, so bring it back 2 indents. Like so:

```
s = 'fddjhkloeavhkiyaeio'
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
count = 0

for i in s:
    if i in vowels:
        count = count + 1

print("Number of vowels: " , str(count))
```