# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable error in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
counter = 0
for i in len(s):
    if i in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
        counter += 1
print("Number of vowels:" + str(counter))
```

I'm trying to make a program that counts the number of vowels assuming that `s` is a string that is predefined. But I'm getting an error:

> 'int' object is not iterable error in python

Comment: `for i in s` instead of `for i in len(s)`

Comment: Use `for i in s` not `for i in len(s)` - the latter means `for i in however_long_your_string_is` and does not make sense

Comment: Also: see [count-vowels-in-string-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python) for a solution if you want to peek. Also2: `if i in "aeiou":` would work as well - and i is a char, not an int so maybe call it `c` ;)

Answer (score 5):

I'll make my answer a bit longer than it should be.

If you don't need a numerical representation `i` of your index for operations within your loop, you just iterate over the string:

```
for i in s:
    do_something()
```

If you only need a numerical representation `i`, e.g. you have a 'string', but you *need* [0,1,2,3,4,5], you can do this:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    do_something(i)
```

Let's break it down. `s` is a `str()`. `len` returns the length of an object as an integer value, for example, `len('string') = 6`. You can't iterate over an integer, because python's `for` is actually a `foreach`. So you need an iterable object, which is `range(len(s))`

If you need *both* the symbol and the index, you can do this:

```
for i, symbol in enumerate(s):
    do_something(i,symbol)
```

For example, this snippet of code:

```
for i, symbol in enumerate('string'):
    print(i,symbol)
```

Will result in:

```
0 s
1 t
2 r
3 i
4 n
5 g
```

Answer (score 1):

`len()` returns type int as length of the string `s` in your case. 
Use `for i in s:` as @Patrick Artner suggested. 
Alternatively you can use

```
for i in range(len(s)):
  curChar=s[i]
```