# assigning variable after unpacking values from the map

Tags: python

From this answer I learned how can I count occurrences of any character in a string using a `map`,

[Count Vowels in String Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python)

Here is my code which counts occurance of any vowels in a string,

```
name = "maverick dean"
vowels = 'aeiou'
x = list(map(name.lower().count, 'aeiou'))
```

As you can see I used list to put each value of a `map` in a `list`.

Which gives this output,

```
[2, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

My desire output is

```
[ "a:2", "e:2", "i:1", "o:0", "u:0" ]
```

Now I understand I can use `for` loop to do it, but is there any other way to map output of `x` directly so that it shows alongside the actual vowel?

Comment: Use a lambda. When you need to use a lambda in a `map` then a list comprehension is probably better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) for this:

```
x = list(map(lambda v: "{}:{}".format(v, name.lower().count(v)), vowels))
print(x)
# ['a:2', 'e:2', 'i:1', 'o:0', 'u:0']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension

```
x = ["%s:%d" % (letter, name.lower().count(letter)) for letter in vowels]
```

or you could even use a zip onto the original list i.e.

```
x = ["%s:%d" % (l,c) for l, c in zip(vowels, map(name.lower().count, vowels))]
```