# There's a easier way to detect vowels in python?

Tags: python

I was doing some exercises to train python and improve, etc. And then i got one that asked me to develop a program that read a letter and print if it is a vowel or a consonant.

```
if(letter== 'a' or letter == 'A' or letter == 'e' or letter == 'E' or letter == 'i' or letter == 'I' or letter == 'o' or letter == 'O' or letter == 'u' or letter == 'U'):
    print(f"{letter} it's a vow.")
elif((letter.isalpha()) == False):
    print('I said letter, not numbers')
else:
    print(f'{letter} it's a consonant.')
```

Anyway, this got really bigger than i wanted and it's really ugly also it's a pain in the ass type all those letters. 
I want to know if there's a way to detect if it's a vow or a consonant with python, importing or not a package to do that. 
Tried searching only but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You could do `letter.lower() in 'aeiou'` to check if it is a wovel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count Vowels in String Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python)

Comment: Check the link above, it's your exact question with many well written answers.

Comment: Don't forget about y!  Edge cases always make things more interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `str.lower` (or `str.upper`) method and the `str in str` operator:

```
# or, if letter.upper() in 'AEIOU':
if letter.lower() in 'aeiou':
    print(f"{letter} it's a vow.")
elif not letter.isalpha():
    print("I said letter, not numbers")
else:
    print(f"{letter} it's a consonant.")
```