# Is there a way to shorten multiple if statements?

Tags: python

This is a program to count all the vowels in a word, the majority of the program is multiple if statements, is there any way I could shorten this?

```
word = input("enter a word ").lower()
a, e, i , o , u = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
letters = [char for char in word]
for x in range(0,len(letters)):
    if letters[x] == "a":
        a += 1
    elif letters[x] == "e":
        e += 1
    elif letters[x] == "i":
        i += 1
    elif letters[x] == "o":
        o += 1
    elif  letters[x] == "u":
        u += 1
print(f"The word `{word}` has {a} `a` characters, {e} `e` characters, {i} `i` characters, {o} `o` characters, {u} `u` characters")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count Vowels in String Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python)

Comment: [Most efficient way of making an if-elif-elif-else statement when the else is done the most?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17166074/6045800)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use 5 separate variables, one per vowel. Use a single `dict` with vowel keys.

```
vowels = "aeiou"
vowel_counts = { x: 0 for x in vowels }

for x in letters:
    if x in vowels:
        vowel_counts[x] += 1

print(f"The word `{word}` has {vowel_counts['a']} `a` characters, {vowel_counts['e']} `e` characters, {vowel_counts['i']} `i` characters, {vowel_counts['o']} `o` characters, {vowel_counts['u']} `u` characters")
```

Comment: And then use the `Counter` class which was built for this: `Counter(letters)` will collate a count of all letters, `Counter(l for l in letters where l in vowels)` will only count vowels (and is probably slower on account of executing the filter). And either way this code will have issues because it doesn't take diacritics in account e.g. `résumé` may or may not account for two `e` depending on the [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) of the input text.

Comment: This is actually the best way. :D