# How to count the number of occurrence for each vowel in a given string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The ideal results below:

```
    >>> count_number_of_each_vowel("Zoo")
    {'o': 2}
    >>> count_number_of_each_vowel("Anaconda")
    {'a': 3, 'o': 1}
    >>> count_number_of_each_vowel("Programming and Data Analysis")
    {'o': 1, 'a': 6, 'i': 2}
```

Broken/Incomplete code:

```
def count_number_of_each_vowel(x: str) -> dict:
    x = x.lower()
    vowel_counts = []
    for vowel in "aeiou":
        count = lowercase.count(vowel)
        vowel_counts[vowel] = count
    return vowel_counts
```

Please help fix this broken code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count Vowels in String Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python)

Answer (score 1):

One of the many approaches:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def count_number_of_each_vowel(data):
    out = defaultdict(lambda:0)
    for word in data.lower():
        if word in "aeiou":
            out[word]+=1
            
    return dict(out)
print (count_number_of_each_vowel("Programming and Data Analysis"))
```

Output:

```
{'o': 1, 'a': 6, 'i': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
a_string = "Anaconda"
lowercase = a_string.lower()
vowel_counts = {}

for vowel in "aeiou":
    count = lowercase.count(vowel)

    vowel_counts[vowel] = count


print(vowel_counts)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(vowel_counts)
{'a': 3, 'e': 0, 'i': 0, 'o': 1, 'u': 0}
```

Code Source:
https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-count-the-vowels-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: Your program's complexity is `O(N^2)`. Can be done in `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_number_of_each_vowel(s):
    return Counter([i for i in s.lower() if i in 'aeiou'])
```

---

```
>>> count_number_of_each_vowel("Zoo")
Counter({'o': 2})
>>>
```

Or with regex:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def count_number_of_each_vowel(s):
    return Counter(re.sub('[^aeiou]', '', s.lower()))
```

---

```
>>> count_number_of_each_vowel("Zoo")
Counter({'o': 2})
>>>
```