# What if you want to show the total number of vowels instead of how many of each vowel are in the string

Tags: python

i am making a code that would help me figure out how many total vowels are in my sequence.
My code looks like this

> vowel = input("type something: abdc ")

> print(*map(vowel.lower().count,"aeiou"))

This kind of code would get me an answer that looks like this "1 0 0 0 0".

This works fine, but the problem is that I want it to show me the total amount of vowels like, this "The amount of vowels in this string is ________.
Could anyone help me edit my code to make it like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885108/11483646

Answer (score 0):

based on what you have you could just do

```
sum(list(map(vowel.lower().count,"aeiou")))
```

to convert the map to a list and then sum up all of those values to get the total number of vowels in a string.

Comment: thannk you for this.

Comment: Could try this too - `sum(1 for c in vowel.lower() if c in 'aeiou')`  Don't need `list` and could be a little faster.