# Python program to count the number of vowels in a given input

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have written a basic code to count the number of vowels in a given string using a for loop.
I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of writing the code?

The code which works:

```
words = input(str("Enter a word:")) #String input from user
words_list = list(words) #Convert user input to a list
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"] #Define vowels list
number = 0 #No: of vowels set to 0
for word in words_list: 
    if word in vowels: 
        number += 1 
print(f"The number of vowels in {words} are {number}")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967001/count-vowels-in-string-python

Answer (score 0):

fastest code for most strings

```py
sum(map(mystring.lower().count, 'aeiou'))
```

Using high performance numpy operations is faster for very large strings

```py
import numpy as np
words = input(str("Enter a word:"))
mystringarray = np.frombuffer(words.lower().encode('ascii', 'ignore'), dtype=np.uint8)
vowels = np.frombuffer("aeiou".encode('ascii'), dtype=np.uint8)
count = np.isin(mystringarray, vowels).sum()
```

using list a list comprehension (instead of a generator) with an if statement after instead of summing true and false is slightly faster, but still slower than using map count

```py
vowels = set('aeiou')
count = sum([1 for c in words.lower() if c in vowels])
```

[benchmarks](https://github.com/arrmansa/vowel-counting-speed-python/blob/main/Vowel_counting_speed.ipynb) for anyone interested

Comment: This *may* be more efficient for very large strings but otherwise it's incredibly slow

Comment: the break even is ~300 chars. for 20,000 chars it's 100us vs 2ms, so 20 times faster.

Comment: When compared to the regular expression solution (see link to duplicate question) the break-even point is with a string length of ~4700 when tested on Python 3.11.2, macOS 13.2.1, 32GB RAM, 3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could use regex, and do:

```py
import re
words = input("Enter a word: ")
number = len(re.findall("[aeiou]", words))

print(f"The number of vowels in {words} are {number}")
```